# Hiding ID in Codeigniter URL

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to understand and use codeigniter routes to hide my ID which is passed to the controllers.

The URL is :

```
http://172.24.130.150/umobility/user/index/2
```

Here,

**`umobility`** is my project name.

**`user`** is my controller name.

I searched the site and found i can define route like this :

```
$route['user/index/(:any)'] = "user/index/$1/$2";
```

But still this does not hide the ID at last of URL.

Please explain and help

Comment: why do you want to hide it?

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo user might change the id from URL, this will allow to send any ID to the controller which can be handled but still i dont want this

Comment: @Rajan, You can use it as a library in CodeIgniter https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/encryption.html

Comment: Is this expected only for logged in user to request own id in URL?

Comment: @Tpojka its expected that the logged in user might not just put some random id at the back of url and pass that id to controller

Comment: If those URLs are meant for logged in users and particularly only for users to see own page(s), you can use session variable instead URI segment. For example, you won't crawl database by value from URL but rather from value from session.

Comment: @Tpojka that can be done but i would increase my code dependency on session values, which i don't prefer. i thought there could be some other alternative

Comment: On user create, store some encrypted value in additional field in database in users table (for example `slug`) and use that value in URI segment.

Answer (score 1):

```
$route['user/(:any)'] = 'user/user_by_name/$1';
```

This will re-route everything to a "user_by_name" method within your user controller, which you'll need to query the database using the name.

http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html

Comment: sorry but umobility is my project name. User is my controller

Answer (score 1):

You can base64 encode the id in the link which doesn't hide it but makes it slightly obscure.

In view...

```
// http://172.24.130.150/umobility/user/index/2

$b64_uid = urlencode(base64_encode($user_id));

echo anchor('user/index/' . $b64_uid, 'Anchor Back to User');

// should create link like http://172.24.130.150/umobility/user/index/Mg%3D%3D
```

In controller...

```
public function index($b64_uid = NULL) {

  // did we get an id?
  if (is_null($b64_uid)) {
    redirect($this->_redirect_url);
  }

  // decode it.
  $user_id = base64_decode(urldecode($b64_uid));

  // validate.
  if (!is_numeric($user_id)) {
    redirect($this->_redirect_url);
  }

  // do something with $user_id...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<form action="function_name" method="POST">` instead of adding ID in URL.

Comment: yes i can do that but we cannot use form elements for each request, also this will make the `reconfirm form submission`  mandatory if user clicks on back button

Comment: try encrypt and decrypt method to safe your variables
link is here
https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/encryption.html